# Selecting the correct projection for NAD_1983_HARN_WISCRS_Bayfield_County_Feet

Tags: geoserver, coordinate-system

I am trying to map the following projection but having issues finding a one that works. I ahve used http://prj2epsg.org/search which gives a few results but none seem to work that well.

```
PROJCS["NAD_1983_HARN_WISCRS_Bayfield_County_Feet", 
GEOGCS["GCS_North_American_1983_HARN", 
DATUM["D_North_American_1983_HARN", 
SPHEROID["GRS_1980", 6378137.0, 298.257222101]], 
PRIMEM["Greenwich", 0.0], 
UNIT["degree", 0.017453292519943295], 
AXIS["Longitude", EAST], 
AXIS["Latitude", NORTH]], 
PROJECTION["Lambert_Conformal_Conic_2SP"], 
PARAMETER["central_meridian", -91.15277777777777], 
PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin", 46.66964837722222], 
PARAMETER["scale_factor", 1.0000331195], 
PARAMETER["false_easting", 750000.0010000002], 
PARAMETER["false_northing", 487372.65900000004], 
UNIT["foot_survey_us", 0.3048006096012192], 
AXIS["X", EAST], 
AXIS["Y", NORTH]]
```

Use Prj2EPSG with the text above (which is what geoserver sees as the native SRS), I get matched with 2236,2241,2239,2254,2257,2260..etc

When I use the prj file instead, I get this.

```
PROJCS["NAD_1983_HARN_WISCRS_Bayfield_County_Feet",
GEOGCS["GCS_North_American_1983_HARN",
DATUM["D_North_American_1983_HARN",
SPHEROID["GRS_1980",6378137.0,298.257222101]],
PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],
UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],
PROJECTION["Lambert_Conformal_Conic"],
PARAMETER["False_Easting",750000.001],
PARAMETER["False_Northing",487372.659],
PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",-91.15277777777779],
PARAMETER["Standard_Parallel_1",46.66964837722222],
PARAMETER["Scale_Factor",1.0000331195],
PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",46.66964837722222],
UNIT["Foot_US",0.3048006096012192]]
```

These match with 3857,24370..etc Obviously the two are different. Geoserver must be parsing it a bit different than prj2epsg does. prj2epsg uses the exact text of the prj file.

After trying to set a few of the declared SRS. When I go to Data->Layer Preview. The layer will show up how it should look just fine. However, when I go to Tile caching -> Tile Layers, both the 4326 and 900913 don't show anything. Typically they show up just fine with most of my other layers. Granted those were easier to use since they were 4326 to start with.

Any suggestions would be helpful.

EDIT: When I select 2236 for example. I can get it to work. However, it shows up in flordia instead of wisconsin. That makes sense since it is pretty much trying to project it on the map in florida. Sounds like I need a custom projection for this? Not sure?

Comment: the difference is your false easting/northing. which inthis case would be a custom projection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to figure it out. I had to create a custom project and add it to geoserver. At first, I was trying to find pre-defined projection thinking they were complicated to add to the system but it was much easier than what I though. I took a previously defined user projection in geoserver and just copied and pasted parts of the projection of the layer to it. What I needed up with was.

```
10001=PROJCS["NAD_1983_HARN_WISCRS_Bayfield_County_Feet",
GEOGCS["GCS_North_American_1983_HARN",
DATUM["D_North_American_1983_HARN",
SPHEROID["GRS_1980",6378137.0,298.257222101]],
PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],
UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],
PROJECTION["Lambert_Conformal_Conic"],
PARAMETER["False_Easting",750000.001],
PARAMETER["False_Northing",487372.659],
PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",-91.15277777777779],
PARAMETER["Standard_Parallel_1",46.66964837722222],
PARAMETER["Scale_Factor",1.0000331195],
PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",46.66964837722222],
UNIT["US_Foot",0.3048006096012192],AUTHORITY["EPSG","10001"]]
```

It was nearly a copy and paste of the layers projection to the custom one. However, still needed to define the number and authority. Take this (as one line, no returns) and paste it into /data_dir/user_projections/epsg.properties.

Answer (score 1):

You will not get lucky with predefined EPSG codes, because these are not defined for all local CRS in the world.

gdalsrsinfo on the WKT definition returns:

`+proj=lcc +lat_1=0 +lat_2=0 +lat_0=46.66964837722222 +lon_0=-91.15277777777777 +x_0=228600.4575057151 +y_0=148551.4835661671 +ellps=GRS80 +units=us-ft +no_defs`

So you have to create a custom CRS to work with that projection in Geoserver, or any other GIS software that works with PROJ.4/GDAL.